# SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)') during performance testing in Locust for the upload PUT request

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, performance-testing, locust

Test execution is in Locust based on HttpUser on MacOS. I'm receiving that kind of error during the upload of file testing, for the file with ~10 MB. The error appears only for more users than 40, rps rate is always equal to users.
I reviewed many topics about SSL errors, I've upgraded all packages related to OpenSSL, also I installed packages related to httpsclient, but it didn't solve the issue, still, for a few PUT requests I'm receiving

```
PUT doc_upload_bigSize_PUT_method: SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)')
```

I'm not so experienced in performance tests, so maybe the fault is on my side, but still, it is strange that a lot of requests are passing, but 2-3 of them are returning SSLEOF.

This is how it looks from a script perspective:
upload method:

```
@staticmethod
def file_upl_pdf(dirname, file_name):
    upload = open(f"{dirname}/{file_name}", "rb")
    return upload
```

Test script:

```
def upload_big_size_doc(self):
    file_name = "test_file_big_size.pdf"
    res = self.client.post("/documents", data=json.dumps(data)), name='doc_upload_bigSize_POST_method')
    json_response = json.loads(res.text)
    document_id = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_response, "documentId")[0]
    url_upload = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_response, "url")[0]
    self.client.put(url=url_upload, data=ResourceUtils.file_upl_pdf(dirname="../test_files/big_size", file_name=file_name),
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'},
                    name='doc_upload_bigSize_PUT_method')
```

here I'm running a test:

```
@task
def perf_test(self):
    self.upload_big_size_doc()
```

I would like to see rather errors coming from load tests about infra like timeout or something, but SSLEOF seems to me like a bad behaviour of my scripts or config.

Comment: Probably your server closed the connection, but it is impossible to say where the error really lies. Maybe try using FastHttpUser to see if it works better/differently?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've already tried that one and unfortunately, it was even worse in terms of the number of errors related to SSLEOF

Comment: You can get some trace loggings using this: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html#print-http-communication
But if both FastHttpUser and HttpUser are having issues, it is probably a purely server-side issue, and the detailed logs will most likely not tell you anything more.

Comment: Actually, there is one improvement you might want to try: Dont read the pdf every time. Read it once, store the data (on module or class level), and reuse it.